# C: strtok returns all values to printf and only half of the values to array

Tags: c, string, strtok

This should tokenize space delimited fields in the string str:

```
float values[2*linesnum(str, length)];
char * pch;
pch = strtok(str, " ");
while (pch != NULL) {
    printf("%s\n", pch);
    pch = strtok(NULL, " ");
}
```

linesnum() just counts the number of '\n' characters in a string.  The above code correctly prints all values from str that I expect.

However, this prints only the first value, and then every second value thereafter:

```
int k = 0;
float values[2*linesnum(data, length)];
char * pch;
pch = strtok(data, " ");
while (pch != NULL) {
    values[k] = atof(pch);
    //printf("%s\n", pch);
    printf("%f\n", values[k]);
    pch = strtok(NULL, " ");
    k++;
}
```

Here is an example of what the input string looks like:

```
3.31 2.16
4.28 0.56
7.20 3.09
11.18 5.06
```

In the first code, it will print out:

```
3.31
2.16
4.28
0.56
7.20
3.09
11.18
5.06
```

In the second code, it will print out:

```
3.310000
2.160000
0.560000
3.090000
5.060000
```

I must be doing something silly.  Is it putting only half of the values into the array?  Why, if all the values show up when I directly print the string pch?  It is as if the single command `pch = strtok(NULL, " ");` is producing two output, and I can capture only one.

Comment: Tip: Never write code that fills an array without checking your array index. In your code above you have no idea if strtok will return more than `2*linesnum(data,length)` and if it does your program is dead, dead, dead.

Comment: Given the specification of the files that are fed in, strtok should always produce exactly 2 times the number of lines in the file.  With that said, your advice is correct and appreciated.

Comment: Don't _tell_ us how you changed the code. _Show_ us the exact unedited code that's causing the problem.

Comment: When you say "only half the values", do you mean every second one or do you mean the first half? It sounds like you mean every second one, but I thought I'd make sure.

Comment: @Ken: Every second one.  (With the exception of the very first value, which is there).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem appears to be that your string looks something like this: `"1.234 5.678\n9.012 3.456"`, that is, the second and third numbers (and the fourth and fifth numbers, and so on) are separated by a `'\n'` character, instead of a `' '` character. To remedy this, you can just add `'\n'` to your string of delimiter characters:

```
pch = strtok(NULL, " \n");
```

Just a note: the reason your original code appears to work is that the second value read is actually (in my example) `"5.678\n9.012"`, which, when printed, looks like

```
5.678
9.012
```

Even though it looks like two values, in reality it is only one string.

Comment: Oh, of course!  I was tricked into thinking that strtok automatically broke on '\n'.  Thank you!

Comment: Yes, and that's why one should output strings like `printf("\'%s\'\n", pch);` in order to see the extents.